# How to copy bytes into clipboard with Python and PyClip

Tags: python, clipboard, copy-paste

I am trying to use [PyClip](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/) to copy and paste into and form clipboard.

These work correctly:

```py
import pyclip
pyclip.copy("ab")
print(list(pyclip.paste()))
```

returns

```
[97, 98]
```

```py
import pyclip
pyclip.copy("ab")
print(pyclip.paste(text=True))
```

returns

```
ab
```

But now I want to copy to clipboard "ab" but in the form of bytes:

```py
import pyclip
pyclip.copy(bytes(97))
print(pyclip.paste(text=True))
```

returns some garbage

So how to copy into clipboard bytes 97 and 98 that when pasted somewhere else I would got "ab"?

**Update:**

To be more precise. I want to copy a string into clipboard in the form of bytes by Python and then by pressing CTRL+V in windows I want the same string to be pasted somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

repl help of `bytes`:

```
class bytes(object)
 |  bytes(iterable_of_ints) -> bytes
 |  bytes(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytes
 |  bytes(bytes_or_buffer) -> immutable copy of bytes_or_buffer
 |  bytes(int) -> bytes object of size given by the parameter initialized with null bytes
 |  bytes() -> empty bytes object
```

So, my guess is that when you do `pyclip.copy(bytes(97))` .. that maps to `bytes(int)` so, you get bytes object with null bytes and its size is 97, eg:

```py
>>> len(bytes(97))
97
>>>
```

Maybe you want something like:

```py
pyclip.copy(bytes([97, 98]))
```

Comment: But why it adds the "b" before it? It returns "b'ab'" when pasted back by python. Also when I try to paste into, say google search bar in my web browser by pressing CTRL+V I got nothing. I would expect that "ab" should be pasted.

Comment: @azerbajdzan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: I updated my question. I want the "copy into clipboard done by Python" to be available inside windows.

Comment: @azerbajdzan  It should work, the example you gave was just wrong because of wrong  usage of `bytes()`  - you where passing a *single int*, not iterable.

Comment: I agree, it should, but it does not. I typed exactly as you wrote `pyclip.copy(bytes([97, 98]))` but when I press `CTRL+V` it does not paste anything like if clipboard was empty.

Comment: On the other hand when I use `pyclip.copy("ab")` and then press `CTRL+V` in windows I got pasted `ab` as required.

Comment: Seems to be windows related then as it works straight up like that in Mac. Maybe you could add the encoding argument to `pyclip.copy()`

Comment: I tried all different encodings, none of them work. Is there any other way to work with clipboard than using `PyClip`?